# Local notification for android app

Tags: android

I want to implement local notification to my android app. when it is in background it shows a notification that the alarm is now starting.I don't know how to start with it .Can anyone suggest me step by step process to move ahead or with any sample project related with this.
Your help will be appreciated

Comment: what have u tried? @Student

Comment: followed this link-http://chrisharrington1.wordpress.com/2012/03/27/android-notifications-and-how-to-send-them-to-the-current-activity/